# Nested For Loop Control Flow Sequence

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

```
for PRODUCT in ${AAA} ${BBB} ${CCC}; do
  for GITBRANCH in ${AAA_BRANCH} ${BBB_BRANCH} ${CCC_BRANCH}; do
    cd ${PRODUCT}
    git checkout ${GITBRANCH}
done;
done
```

My nested `for loop` in `bash` (above) does:

- `cd` under AAA repo and check out AAA_BRANCH
- `cd` under AAA repo and check out BBB_BRANCH
- `cd` under AAA repo and check out CCC_BRANCH
- `cd` under BBB repo and check out AAA_BRANCH
- `cd` under BBB repo and check out BBB_BRANCH
- `cd` under BBB repo and check out CCC_BRANCH
- `cd` under CCC repo and check out AAA_BRANCH
- `cd` under CCC repo and check out BBB_BRANCH
- `cd` under CCC repo and check out CCC_BRANCH

I want my loop to:

- `cd` under AAA repo and check out AAA_BRANCH
- `cd` under BBB repo and check out BBB_BRANCH
- `cd` under CCC repo and check out CCC_BRANCH

How can I accomplish this? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrays instead and iterate over indices.

```
products=(aaa bbb ccc)
branches=(aaa_branch bbb_branch ccc_branch)
for i in "${!products[@]}"; do
  cd "${products[i]}"
  git checkout "${branches[i]}"
  cd -
done
```